# Configure clickonce deploy so that user can find and open included pdf file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, clickonce

I created a Documentation folder in my project, and added the user guide, a pdf file, to my project (as content, copy if newer)

Using a click-once deploy, the file is copied - but casual users will not be able to navigate to its location using explorer.  How can I configure the deployment to make it easy for the user to find this file when they want to read it?

Comment: A solution might be as I suggested on a recent post [here]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14906858/defining-where-files-are-installed/14940482#14940482

Comment: Thanks, I think that will be helpful.  I'll probably use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(PATH_REPORTS & "\\MyPDF.pdf")` from a Help\Documentation menu item, and let the OS open it with the default pdf file reader.  I think it will be easier, in the long run, then copying it elsewhere manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there is a ClickOnce solution to this, you need to create the folder after first run (for example ProgramFiles/Appl) and copy the help file to the folder manually.

Comment: Or, use Process.Start to open it for the user from within the application.  Those are the only options that seem to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to handle this is to copy the file to MyDocuments/yourappname/appdata/ when your application starts up or when the user asks for hte file, and then direct the user to it there.